# Open python applet, quit enclosing applet

Tags: python

This is really hard to put into words.

I have two applets: Applet A and Applet B. Applet A needs to be able to open Applet B based on a certain interaction, then quit itself, and vice versa.

Here's kind of what I'm looking for:

```
#Applet A

if [user interaction]
    open Applet B
    quit Applet A, but keep B open
```

---

```
#Applet B

if [another user interaction]
    open Applet A
    quit Applet B, but keep A open
```

(obviously this would be actual code, but trying to keep it simple here)

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to understand fully what you mean, but you could use os.system to start the next process.

```
import os, sys
os.system('python appletB.py')
sys.exit(0)
```

A better way of doing this is to not use two processes and just use two threads with a master process to control each. Then it gets a bit complicated with making sure the variables are thread-safe if you want to communicate between them.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks. Any chance you could give me a quick starting point for the threads and master option? Any resources would be greatly appreciated as I'm fairly new to python.

Comment: Here's a good example of how you would use threading: http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/09/simplistic-python-thread-example/